# Why I can't use Template.FindName()

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a method like this:

```
public void vtornik ()
{
    Image mon = (Image)Monday.Template.FindName("monday_2", Monday);
    mon.Opacity = 0;
}
```

And i call it from my button click:

```
private void Thuesday_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    vtornik();
}
```

The template looks like this:

```
<Style x:Key="monday" TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
  <Style.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="OnMouseLeftButtonUp1"/>
  </Style.Resources>
  <Style.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UIElement.MouseLeftButtonUp">
      <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource OnMouseLeftButtonUp1}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
        <ControlTemplate.Resources>
          <Storyboard x:Key="OnMouseLeftButtonUp1">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="monday_2">
              <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
          </Storyboard>
        </ControlTemplate.Resources>
        <Grid>
          <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ValidationStates">
              <VisualState x:Name="Valid"/>
              <VisualState x:Name="InvalidFocused"/>
              <VisualState x:Name="InvalidUnfocused"/>
            </VisualStateGroup>
          </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
          <Image
            x:Name="monday_1"
            Source="images/monday_1.png"
            Stretch="Fill"
            Opacity="0"/>
          <Image
            x:Name="monday_2"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
            Height="Auto" Width="Auto"
            Margin="0" Source="images/monday_2.png"
            Stretch="Fill" Opacity="0"/>
          <ScrollViewer>
            <ItemsPresenter/>
          </ScrollViewer>
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="monday_1" Value="1"/>
          </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Why can I successfully call this method from the button click but cant use it without button click?

I get NullReference exeption - method cant find image and then:

"An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll"

Comment: When you are calling it not from the button click has the template been applied?

Comment: i dont know. i think that it dont cuz i cant find the template resources. how i can check is template applied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the template is being applied (or the listbox you are trying to get the image from has loaded), to do this you could try a few different things.

You could use the [`FrameworkElement.OnApplyTemplate` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.onapplytemplate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to do what you need to do when the template has been applied.

> When overridden in a derived class, is invoked whenever application
>   code or internal processes call ApplyTemplate.

Or in some cases you could try calling the [`FrameworkElement.ApplyTemplate()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.applytemplate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to try and force the element to apply its template.

> Builds the current template's visual tree if necessary, and returns a
>   value that indicates whether the visual tree was rebuilt by this call.